# why cant SqlDataReader class be inherited?

Tags: .net, sqldatareader

[`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) class is not marked sealed then what makes it uninheritable?

Comment: Why do you want to inherit from it? Use extension methods instead!

Comment: i dont want to inherit it. just noticed that its not marked sealed but said to be uninheritable so just asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SqlDataReader` type's constructor is marked as `internal` which means it can only be instantiated through types in the `System.Data.dll` assembly.  This also prohibits you from inheriting from it, as the base type cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Its only constructor is marked as internal, so it cannot be called by any non-framework code.