# What makes SqlDataReader class in C# non-inheritable or non-Instantiable

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

There is an need to appreciate how C# has made SqlDataReader class Non Inheritable and Non Instantiable.

Namespace:   System.Data.SqlClient

**SqlDataReader class header :**

```
public class SqlDataReader : System.Data.Common.DbDataReader, IDisposable, System.Data.Common.IDbColumnSchemaGenerator{

}
```

**Question 1:**
The class seen is public.

Since the class is public :: So why can't it be inherited.

**Question 2:**
*Constructor is not Private : Infact on seeing the definition of SqlDataReader :  no constructor was seen ::* So i guess the Default constructor that C# will label to it to be default would be a Public one which happens when no constructor is found  ::
So despite, supposedly, having a Public constructor why should the Instantiation not be possible.

Besides I can't find the constructor to be "internal" as was answered and accepted in this question link :
[why cant SqlDataReader class be inherited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921512/why-cant-sqldatareader-class-be-inherited)

Would be highly appreciative if the point of error in the above thinking can be highlighted.

Comment: "Constructor is not Private" how do you know? Do you have access to the source code?. Also, your linked question does not state that the class is internal, only the *constructor*. Which means that the class is visible from outside the `System.Data` dll, but cannot be instantiated from outside it, meaning you also cannot inherit it as any class inheriting from it cannot instantiate its base class

Comment: It´s literally in the duplicate: "The SqlDataReader type's constructor is marked as internal".

Comment: "internal SqlDataReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)": From the source-code: `internal SqlDataReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) { ... }`. How did you examine the "sourcecode"? Probably with some tool that just decompiles an assembly. However that does not neccessarily give youe the **actual** code.

Comment: HimBromBeere : Thanks for answering : Yes it was a duplicate and needed an answer for someone who has started to begin questioning on basics quite late. However the question did not allow me to ask again as i had no points. In just few mins even this question was closed by some other member i guess. Any suggestions wht better course i could have followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which source code you are looking at (Probably a basic disassembly).
Have a look at the github [SqlDataReader Source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs)

It has internal constructor only and hence it cant be instantiated.

Comment: Jack: Thanks I was so far looking at the Definition (F12) in the Visual Studio Code....thinking it would even show me the Constructor's metadata as well.

Comment: Ya, that just shows you the declarations.